# fabric-sdk-node: Error: Failed to parse key from PEM: not supported argument

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I've been trying for a while without success to connect to a network (local-network generated via the vscode blockchain-vscode-extension) via the connection profile that I was able to extract from vscode extension (see below the output of the extracted file).

Here is the a code for test purpose to connect to the network:

```
  async test(transactionConfig: ITransaction2HLF): Promise<any>{
    ...
    const id = await this.walletProxy.getIdentity("org1Admin")
    if(!id){
      throw new NotFoundException("org1Admin is not register")
    }
    const wallet = this.walletProxy.getWallet();
    const gatewayOptions: GatewayOptions = {
      identity: 'org1Admin', // Previously imported identity
      wallet: wallet
    };
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    const ccp =  joinPathFromCWD(["local-network", "gateway", "Org1", "Org1.json"]);
    const connectionProfileJson = readFileSyncUTF8(ccp).toString();
    const connectionProfile = JSON.parse(connectionProfileJson);
    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, gatewayOptions); // got the error
    return gateway
  }
```

When I try to connect to the network via the Gateway I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to parse key from PEM: not supported argument
    at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.createKeyFromRaw (D:\dev\...\cib\delivrable\cib-ledger-api\node_modules\fabric-common\lib\impl\CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:135:10)
    at X509Provider.getUserContext (D:\dev\...\cib\delivrable\cib-ledger-api\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\impl\wallet\x509identity.js:52:46)
    at Gateway.connect (D:\dev\...\cib\delivrable\cib-ledger-api\node_modules\fabric-network\lib\gateway.js:237:41)
```

here the format of the connection profile:

```
{
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "Org1CA": {
        "caName": "ca",
        "url": "http://localhost:17050"
    }
},
"client": {
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "orderer": "300",
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "organization": "Org1MSP"
},
"name": "Org1",
"organizations": {
    "Org1MSP": {
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "Org1CA"
        ],
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "Org1Peer1"
        ]
    }
},
"peers": {
    "Org1Peer1": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:17051"
    }
},
"version": "1.0.0",
"wallet": "Org1"
```

}

I currently use the vscode blockchain-vscode-extension plugin and the following packages:

```
"fabric-ca-client": "^2.2.0",
"fabric-network": "^2.2.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem with "org1Admin"'s private key.